# How to create dynamic view in MVC4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing my content based website which will display all content title and a link on the same will be attached. The link pattern will be like this

```
www.mydomain.com/category/nobel-award-2012    
www.mydomain.com/category/spain-win-the-world-cup-football
```

these url will be generated dynamically and I want to handle this situation through single `view` & `controller`. Whenever any new content will be added a new link will be generated automatically.

Any one can help me to design my view as well controller.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Creation of **dynamic views** pretty much has the same approach starting from the version MVC 2.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>
```

You may easily look at this following tutorial and get an idea:
 - [Dynamic Views in ASP.NET MVC 2](http://www.gregshackles.com/2010/07/dynamic-views-in-asp-net-mvc-2/).

You may also need to use a **customized URL Routing** as described in this article - [**Understanding Routing in ASP.NET MVC**](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=814) -

Comment: hi ElYusubov, Thanks for your response. As per your suggestion, this view will work for all content with in a category?? If yes what will be the controller structure?